# Looking up enum label by value

Tags: java, android, enums

I have the following enum in my java android application:

```
static enum PaymentType
{           
    Scheme(0), Topup(1), Normal(2), Free(3), Promotion(4), Discount(5), Partial(6),
    Refund(7), NoShow(8), Prepay(9), Customer(10), Return(11), Change(12), PettyCash(13),
    StateTax(14), LocalTax(15), Voucher(16), Membership(17), Gratuity(18), Overpayment(19),
    PrepayTime(20), HandlingFee(21);

    private int value;

    private PaymentType(int i) {
        value = i;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I use this enum alot to find out the integer value of one of these string labels, for example `int i = Lookups.PaymentType.Voucher.getValue();`.

How can I do this the other way around? I have an integer value from a database and I need to find which string that corresponds to.

Comment: I don't know if `enum` is the right use for a lookup table. A normal class that encapsulates an unmodifiable map would be sufficient.

Comment: Can you explain what the use of `value` is in your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go from an `ordinal()` index value back to enum:

```
type = PaymentType.values()[index];
```

However, keep in mind that this is fragile when the ordinal is stored anywhere else, such as a database. If the index numbers ever change, you'll get invalid results.

For more reliable lookup table, use a Map.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the order of elements within an `enum`. That's kind of the same issue as the use of `ordinal()`.

Comment: However this answer was the one that best answered the question `How can I do this the other way around?` - I'll take everybody's advice on board, thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

You should do something like this (static-init block should be at the end! and in your case just replace "asc" and "desc" with numbers, or add any other field):

```
public enum SortOrder {
    ASC("asc"),
    DESC("desc");

    private static final HashMap<String, SortOrder> MAP = new HashMap<String, SortOrder>();

    private String value;

    private SortOrder(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public static SortOrder getByName(String name) {
        return MAP.get(name);
    }

    static {
        for (SortOrder field : SortOrder.values()) {
            MAP.put(field.getValue(), field);
        }
    }
}
```

After that, just call:

```
SortOrder asc = SortOrder.getByName("asc");
```

Comment: The static block need not be at the end. Personally I'd like to put it next to the `Map` that it initializes.

Comment: This approach is extremely fragile; the `MAP` is mutable. I recommend using a Guava `ImmutableMap` instead.